# jQuery if children have value, make them selected

Tags: jquery

I have a PHP value called `per_page` which I'm carrying on to a jQuery function.

I want the jQuery function to search the `<select id="thisForm">` element for any `<option>` with the text() value equal to `per_page`.

I then want the function to make that `<option>` selected, so it appears like this: `<option selected>`.

I didn't know how to use this() or whatever once I've found the text() value.

**Solution:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var i = 'whatever your per_page value is';
   $("#changeForm option[value=" + i +"]").attr("selected",true);
});
```

Comment: Why are you using javascript to do this? Why not use php when it renders the page to select the correct option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this should work:

```
$('#thisForm option:contains("per_page")').attr('selected',true);
```

Using [`contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5MPRz/) of concept.